# Quotes breakes JS variable

Tags: javascript

I need create var in js script, something like this:

```
var map = "<div class="map"><?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id="3"]'); ?></div>";
```

but apostrophes and quotes breaks code. How to change it to make it works?

Comment: Use single quotes `'`, or template literals. `var map = \`<div class="map">...\`` Having said that, you can create elements without parsing HTML strings. In case the HTML echoed by the PHP part also contains various quotes, that won't help though. A better way is to use AJAX to load the contents. Wordpress supports ajax out of the box.

Comment: [Escape characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation)

Comment: As an aside: since the map canvas(?) is inserted on the server, there's probably no need to go the `var` route. Please show or describe what you're doing with `map`; there's at least one better way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use other quotes or escape them.

```js
var map = `<div class="map"><?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id="3"]'); ?></div>`;

var map2 = "<div class=\"map\"><?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id=\"3\"]'); ?></div>";

console.log(map);
console.log(map2);
```

Comment: I don't understand what quote you are using in the first case. Is this an accent grave?

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that the accent grave could be used since Javascript version "ECMAScript 6"

Comment: Great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes.

```
var map = "<div class=\"map\"><?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id=\"3\"]'); ?></div>";
```

If you open the value with `"` then JavaScript will look for the second `"` to know where the value ends. As you're now using this within the value as well it stops to early. By escaping the `"` that you want to use within your value, you will make sure JavaScript knows it is part of the value.

So in your code, Javascript will stop after the second `"`:
`var map = "<div class="` 
As you can see you did now open it with `"` and after the `=` there is another `"` so the value will be closed. How ever, you still have some more code after it: `map"><?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id=\"3\"]'); ?></div>";`
As JavaScript doesn't  know what to do with this part, it'll throw an error.

**Maybe this will explain it better if you don't understand the above part:**

You can see it as an if statement where `if { }` you need two brackets. One to open `{` and one to close `}`. In your value you need also two characters, one to open and one to close. In your case you use a `"` to open the value and `"` to close. So as soon as it hits the second `"` it'll close the value.

The assignment you did is comparable with this if-statement: `if { } }`. JavaScript doesn't know what to do with the latest `}`, as there is no other `if-statement` to close and because of that reason it'll throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the value of your variable using a few methods:

**Escaping the quotes**

You can add a backslash to the double quotes to make the JS parser ignore them. I would also concatenate the PHP value for clarity:

```
var map = "<div class=\"map\">" + <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id="3"]'); ?> + "</div>";
```

**Using single quotes and double quotes alternatively**

If you need to use double quotes in the value, you can just wrap it with single quotes.

```
var map = '<div class="map">' + <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id="3"]'); ?> + '</div>';
```

It also works the other way around, if you prefer single quotes in HTML attribute values

```
var map = "<div class='map'>" + <?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id="3"]'); ?> + "</div>";
```

**Template literals**

In ES6, you can use template literals using the back-tick character. Notice you can both use single and double quotes inside a template literal:

```
var map = `<div class="map"><?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id="3"]'); ?></div>`;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var map = /"<div class=/"map/"><?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id=/"3/"]'); ?></div>/";
```

or

```
var map = "<div class='map'><?php echo do_shortcode('[wpgmza id='3']'); ?></div>";
```

Comment: Fixed your question's formatting, but it's still wrong. Masking is done with backslashes, and one wouldn't mask the outer quotes.